# python: padding punctuation with white spaces (keeping punctuation)

Tags: python, regex, padding

What is an efficient way to pad punctuation with whitespace?

input:

```
s = 'bla. bla? bla.bla! bla...'
```

desired output:

```
 s = 'bla . bla ? bla . bla ! bla . . .'
```

Comments:

1. I don't care how many whitespaces are there between tokens. (but they'll need to be collapsed eventually)
2. I don't want to pad all punctuation. Say I'm interested only in .,!?().

Comment: `<tiny details>` wouldn't you expect a space after the last dot?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the punctuation characters you are interested and surround them by spaces, then use a second step to collapse multiple spaces anywhere in the document:

```py
s = 'bla. bla? bla.bla! bla...'
import re
s = re.sub('([.,!?()])', r' \1 ', s)
s = re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', s)
print(s)
```

Result:

```
bla . bla ? bla . bla ! bla . . .
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use python3, use the maketrans() function.

```
import string   
text = text.translate(str.maketrans({key: " {0} ".format(key) for key in string.punctuation}))
```

Comment: will this match if the punctuation already have space around?

Comment: @MagedSaeed yes

Answer (score 5):

This will add exactly one space if one is not present, and will not ruin existing spaces or other white-space characters:

```
s = re.sub('(?<! )(?=[.,!?()])|(?<=[.,!?()])(?! )', r' ', s)
```

This works by finding a zero-width position between a punctuation and a non-space, and adding a space there.
Note that is *does* add a space on the beginning or end of the string, but it can be easily done by changing the look-arounds to `(?<=[^ ])` and `(?=[^ ])`.

See in in action: **http://ideone.com/BRx7w**

Comment: Here's the version where I don't duplicate too much code (I don't know any Python): http://ideone.com/PuVz5