# How can I add code to visualize the model? my model has encoder-decoder architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, encoder-decoder

How can I add code to visualize the model? I tried to use plot() function. It keeps give me errors to determine initial data. I tried to build the code without functions but with no any improvement. The same error still exists. Kindly, I need a code to visualize this model. Is there any other ways to visualize the model?

```
# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.

import os
import gc
import time
import re
import unicodedata

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

#Importing libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# Global parameters
#root folder
# ==> root_folder='.'
root_folder = '/content/drive/My Drive'
#data_folder='.'
# ==> data_folder_name='data'
data_folder_name='DSetMin'
# ==> train_filename='fra.txt'
train_filename='ATB3_New_Dataset_End_FullStop.txt'

# Variable for data directory
DATA_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root_folder, data_folder_name))
train_filenamepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, train_filename))

# Both train and test set are in the root data directory
train_path = DATA_PATH
# test_path = DATA_PATH
test_path = DATA_PATH

# Parameters for our model
INPUT_COLUMN = 'input'
TARGET_COLUMN = 'target'
TARGET_FOR_INPUT = 'target_for_input'
NUM_SAMPLES = 40000 #30000 #20000
MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 128
HIDDEN_DIM=1024 #512

BATCH_SIZE = 64  # Batch size for training.
EPOCHS = 100 # ==> 50  # 10, Number of epochs to train for.

# ATTENTION_FUNC='general'

# Some function to preprocess the text data, taken from the Neural machine translation with attention tutorial
# in Tensorflow
def unicode_to_ascii(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')

def preprocess_sentence(w):
    ''' Preprocess the input text w applying lowercase, removing accents, 
    creating a space between a word and the punctuation following it and 
    replacing everything with space except (a-z, A-Z, ".", "?", "!", ",")
    Input:
        - w: a string, input text
    Output:
        - a string, the cleaned text
    '''
    # w = unicode_to_ascii(w.lower().strip())

    # creating a space between a word and the punctuation following it
    # eg: "he is a boy." => "he is a boy ."
    # Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645931/python-padding-punctuation-with-white-spaces-keeping-punctuation
    w = re.sub(r"([?.!,¿])", r" \1 ", w)
    w = re.sub(r'[" "]+', " ", w)

    # replacing everything with space except (a-z, A-Z, ".", "?", "!", ",")
    # w = re.sub(r"[أ-ي ًٌٍَُِّْ?.!,¿]+", " ", w)

    w = w.strip()

    # adding a start and an end token to the sentence
    # so that the model know when to start and stop predicting.
    #w = '<start> ' + w + ' <end>'
    
    return w

# Load the dataset: sentence in english, sentence in spanish 
df=pd.read_csv(train_filenamepath, sep="\t", header=None, names=[INPUT_COLUMN,TARGET_COLUMN], usecols=[0,1], 
               nrows=NUM_SAMPLES)
# Preprocess the input data
input_data=df[INPUT_COLUMN].apply(lambda x : preprocess_sentence(x)).tolist()
# Preprocess and include the end of sentence token to the target text
target_data=df[TARGET_COLUMN].apply(lambda x : preprocess_sentence(x)+ ' <eos>').tolist()
# Preprocess and include a start of setence token to the input text to the decoder, it is rigth shifted
target_input_data=df[TARGET_COLUMN].apply(lambda x : '<sos> '+ preprocess_sentence(x)).tolist()

print(input_data[:5])
print(target_data[:5])
print(target_input_data[:5])

# Create a tokenizer for the input texts and fit it to them 
tokenizer_inputs = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, filters='')
tokenizer_inputs.fit_on_texts(input_data)
# Tokenize and transform input texts to sequence of integers
input_sequences = tokenizer_inputs.texts_to_sequences(input_data)
# Claculate the max length
input_max_len = max(len(s) for s in input_sequences)
# print('Max words Input Length: ', input_max_len)
# Show some example of tokenize sentences, useful to check the tokenization
print(input_data[1000])
print(input_sequences[1000])

# tokenize the outputs
# don't filter out special characters (filters = '')
# otherwise <sos> and <eos> won't appear
# By default, Keras’ Tokenizer will trim out all the punctuations, which is not what we want. 
# we can just set filters as blank here.

# Create a tokenizer for the output texts and fit it to them 
tokenizer_outputs = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, filters='')
tokenizer_outputs.fit_on_texts(target_data)
tokenizer_outputs.fit_on_texts(target_input_data)
# Tokenize and transform output texts to sequence of integers
target_sequences = tokenizer_outputs.texts_to_sequences(target_data)
target_sequences_inputs = tokenizer_outputs.texts_to_sequences(target_input_data)

# determine maximum length output sequence
target_max_len = max(len(s) for s in target_sequences)
# print('Max Words Target Length: ', target_max_len)

print(target_data[1000])
print(target_sequences[1000])
print(target_input_data[1000])
print(target_sequences_inputs[1000])

# get the word to index mapping for input language
word2idx_inputs = tokenizer_inputs.word_index
print('Found %s unique input tokens.' % len(word2idx_inputs))

# get the word to index mapping for output language
word2idx_outputs = tokenizer_outputs.word_index
print('Found %s unique output tokens.' % len(word2idx_outputs))

# store number of output and input words for later
# remember to add 1 since indexing starts at 1
num_words_output = len(word2idx_outputs) + 1
num_words_inputs = len(word2idx_inputs) + 1

# map indexes back into real words
# so we can view the results
idx2word_inputs = {v:k for k, v in word2idx_inputs.items()}
idx2word_outputs = {v:k for k, v in word2idx_outputs.items()}

# pad the input sequences
encoder_inputs = pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=input_max_len, padding='post')
# print("encoder_inputs.shape:", encoder_inputs.shape)
print("encoder_inputs[0]:", encoder_inputs[0])
# pad the decoder input sequences
decoder_inputs = pad_sequences(target_sequences_inputs, maxlen=target_max_len, padding='post')
print("decoder_inputs[0]:", decoder_inputs[0])
# print("decoder_inputs.shape:", decoder_inputs.shape)
# pad the target output sequences
decoder_targets = pad_sequences(target_sequences, maxlen=target_max_len, padding='post')

# Define a dataset 
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, decoder_targets))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(input_data)).batch(
    BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        # Define the embedding layer
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        # Define the RNN layer, LSTM
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
            hidden_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)

    def call(self, input_sequence, states):
        # Embed the input
        embed = self.embedding(input_sequence)
        # Call the LSTM unit
        output, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(embed, initial_state=states)

        return output, state_h, state_c

    def init_states(self, batch_size):
        # Return all 0s initial states
        return (tf.zeros([batch_size, self.hidden_dim]),
                tf.zeros([batch_size, self.hidden_dim]))

def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        # Define the embedding layer
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        # Define the RNN layer, LSTM
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
            hidden_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

def call(self, input_sequence, state):
        # Embed the input
        embed = self.embedding(input_sequence)
        # Call the LSTM unit
        lstm_out, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(embed, state)
        # Dense layer to predict output token
        logits = self.dense(lstm_out)

        return logits, state_h, state_c

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        # Define the embedding layer
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        # Define the RNN layer, LSTM
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
            hidden_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    def call(self, input_sequence, state):
        # Embed the input
        embed = self.embedding(input_sequence)
        # Call the LSTM unit
        lstm_out, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(embed, state)
        # Dense layer to predict output token
        logits = self.dense(lstm_out)

        return logits, state_h, state_c

num_words_inputs = len(word2idx_inputs) + 1
num_words_output = len(word2idx_outputs) + 1
#Create the encoder
encoder = Encoder(num_words_inputs, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM)
# Get the initial states
initial_state = encoder.init_states(1)
# Call the encoder for testing
test_encoder_output = encoder(tf.constant(
    [[1, 23, 4, 5, 0, 0]]), initial_state)
print('test_encoder_output:',test_encoder_output[0].shape)
# Create the decoder
decoder = Decoder(num_words_output, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM)
# Get the initial states
de_initial_state = test_encoder_output[1:]
# Call the decoder for testing
test_decoder_output = decoder(tf.constant(
    [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0]]), de_initial_state)
print('test_decoder_output:', test_decoder_output[0].shape)

def loss_func(targets, logits):
    crossentropy = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
        from_logits=True)
    # Mask padding values, they do not have to compute for loss
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(targets, 0))
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.int64)
    # Calculate the loss value
    loss = crossentropy(targets, logits, sample_weight=mask)

    return loss

def accuracy_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    # y_pred shape is batch_size, seq length, vocab size
    # y_true shape is batch_size, seq length
    pred_values = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), dtype='int32')
    correct = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, pred_values), dtype='float32')

    # 0 is padding, don't include those
    mask = K.cast(K.greater(y_true, 0), dtype='float32')
    n_correct = K.sum(mask * correct)
    n_total = K.sum(mask)
  
    return n_correct / n_total

# Use the @tf.function decorator to take advance of static graph computation
@tf.function
def train_step(input_seq, target_seq_in, target_seq_out, en_initial_states, optimizer):
    ''' A training step, train a batch of the data and return the loss value reached
        Input:
        - input_seq: array of integers, shape [batch_size, max_seq_len, embedding dim].
            the input sequence
        - target_seq_out: array of integers, shape [batch_size, max_seq_len, embedding dim].
            the target seq, our target sequence
        - target_seq_in: array of integers, shape [batch_size, max_seq_len, embedding dim].
            the input sequence to the decoder, we use Teacher Forcing
        - en_initial_states: tuple of arrays of shape [batch_size, hidden_dim].
            the initial state of the encoder
        - optimizer: a tf.keras.optimizers.
        Output:
        - loss: loss value
        
    '''
    # Network’s computations need to be put under tf.GradientTape() to keep track of gradients
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Get the encoder outputs
        en_outputs = encoder(input_seq, en_initial_states)
        # Set the encoder and decoder states
        en_states = en_outputs[1:]
        de_states = en_states
        # Get the decoder outputs
        de_outputs = decoder(target_seq_in, de_states)
        # Take the actual output
        logits = de_outputs[0]
        # Calculate the loss function
        loss = loss_func(target_seq_out, logits)
        acc = accuracy_fn(target_seq_out, logits)

    variables = encoder.trainable_variables + decoder.trainable_variables
    # Calculate the gradients for the variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
    # Apply the gradients and update the optimizer
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

    return loss, acc

# Create the main train function
def main_train(encoder, decoder, dataset, n_epochs, batch_size, optimizer, checkpoint, checkpoint_prefix):
    
    losses = []
    accuracies = []

    for e in range(n_epochs):
        # Get the initial time
        start = time.time()
        # Get the initial state for the encoder
        en_initial_states = encoder.init_states(batch_size)
        # For every batch data
        for batch, (input_seq, target_seq_in, target_seq_out) in enumerate(dataset.take(-1)):
            # Train and get the loss value 
            loss, accuracy = train_step(input_seq, target_seq_in, target_seq_out, en_initial_states, optimizer)
        
            if batch % 100 == 0:
                # Store the loss and accuracy values
                losses.append(loss)
                accuracies.append(accuracy)
                print('Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f} Acc:{:.4f}'.format(e + 1, batch, loss.numpy(), accuracy.numpy()))
                
        # saving (checkpoint) the model every 2 epochs
        if (e + 1) % 2 == 0:
            checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
    
        print('Time taken for 1 epoch {:.4f} sec\n'.format(time.time() - start))
        
    return losses, accuracies

# Create an Adam optimizer and clips gradients by norm
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=5.0)
# Create a checkpoint object to save the model
checkpoint_dir = './training_ckpt_seq2seq'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                                 
                                 encoder=encoder,
                                 decoder=decoder)

losses, accuracies = main_train(encoder, decoder, dataset, EPOCHS, BATCH_SIZE, optimizer, checkpoint, checkpoint_prefix)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,5))
# plot some data
ax1.plot(losses, label='loss')
#plt.plot(results.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
ax1.set_title('Training Loss')
ax1.legend()
# accuracies
ax2.plot(accuracies, label='acc')
#plt.plot(results.history['val_accuracy_fn'], label='val_acc')
ax2.set_title('Training Accuracy')
ax2.legend()
plt.show()

!pip install --upgrade bleu
!pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/zhijing-jin/bleu.git
from bleu import file_bleu

# from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

# restoring the latest checkpoint in checkpoint_dir
checkpoint_dir = './training_ckpt_seq2seq'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

def predict(input_text, encoder, input_max_len, tokenizer_inputs, word2idx_outputs, idx2word_outputs):
    if input_text is None:
        input_text = input_data[np.random.choice(len(input_data))]
        print(input_text)
    # Tokenize the input sequence
    input_seq = tokenizer_inputs.texts_to_sequences([input_text])
    # Pad the sentence
    input_seq = pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=input_max_len, padding='post')
    print(input_seq)
    # Set the encoder initial state
    en_initial_states = encoder.init_states(1)
    en_outputs = encoder(tf.constant(input_seq), en_initial_states)
    # Create the decoder input, the sos token
    de_input = tf.constant([[word2idx_outputs['<sos>']]])
    # Set the decoder states to the encoder vector or encoder hidden state
    de_state_h, de_state_c = en_outputs[1:]
    
    out_words = []
    while True:
        # Decode and get the output probabilities
        de_output, de_state_h, de_state_c = decoder(
            de_input, (de_state_h, de_state_c))
        # Select the word with the highest probability
        de_input = tf.argmax(de_output, -1)
        # Append the word to the predicted output
        out_words.append(idx2word_outputs[de_input.numpy()[0][0]])
        # Finish when eos token is found or the max length is reached
        if out_words[-1] == '<eos>' or len(out_words) >= 20:
            break

    print(' '.join(out_words))

test_sents = [input_data[10003], input_data[10120]]
#test_sents = [encoder_inputs[1000]]
print(test_sents)
for test_sent in test_sents:
    predict(test_sent, encoder, input_max_len, tokenizer_inputs, word2idx_outputs, idx2word_outputs)

''' def predict2(input_text, encoder, input_max_len, tokenizer_inputs, word2idx_outputs, idx2word_outputs):
    if input_text is None:
        input_text = input_data[np.random.choice(len(input_data))]
        print(input_text)
    # Tokenize the input sequence
    input_seq = tokenizer_inputs.texts_to_sequences([input_text])
    # Pad the sentence
    input_seq = pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=input_max_len, padding='post')
    print(input_seq)
    # Set the encoder initial state
    en_initial_states = encoder.init_states(1)
    en_outputs = encoder(tf.constant(input_seq), en_initial_states)
    # Create the decoder input, the sos token
    de_input = tf.constant([[word2idx_outputs['<sos>']]])
    # Set the decoder states to the encoder vector or encoder hidden state
    de_state_h, de_state_c = en_outputs[1:]
    
    out_words = []
    while True:
        # Decode and get the output probabilities
        de_output, de_state_h, de_state_c = decoder(
            de_input, (de_state_h, de_state_c))
        # Select the word with the highest probability
        de_input = tf.argmax(de_output, -1)
        # Append the word to the predicted output
        out_words.append(idx2word_outputs[de_input.numpy()[0][0]])
        # Finish when eos token is found or the max length is reached
        if out_words[-1] == '<eos>' or len(out_words) >= 20:
            break

    print(' '.join(out_words))
    f = open('hyp_enc_dec_2L.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(str(' '.join(out_words))+ '\n')
    f.close() '''

def predict3(input_text, encoder, input_max_len, tokenizer_inputs, word2idx_outputs, idx2word_outputs):
    if input_text is None:
        input_text = input_data[np.random.choice(len(input_data))]
        print(input_text)
    # Tokenize the input sequence
    input_seq = tokenizer_inputs.texts_to_sequences([input_text])
    # Pad the sentence
    input_seq = pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=input_max_len, padding='post')
    print(input_seq)
    # Set the encoder initial state
    en_initial_states = encoder.init_states(1)
    en_outputs = encoder(tf.constant(input_seq), en_initial_states)
    # Create the decoder input, the sos token
    de_input = tf.constant([[word2idx_outputs['<sos>']]])
    # Set the decoder states to the encoder vector or encoder hidden state
    de_state_h, de_state_c = en_outputs[1:]
    
    out_words = []
    while True:
        # Decode and get the output probabilities
        de_output, de_state_h, de_state_c = decoder(
            de_input, (de_state_h, de_state_c))
        # Select the word with the highest probability
        de_input = tf.argmax(de_output, -1)
        # Append the word to the predicted output
        out_words.append(idx2word_outputs[de_input.numpy()[0][0]])
        # Finish when eos token is found or the max length is reached
        if out_words[-1] == '<eos>' or len(out_words) >= 20:
            break

    print(' '.join(out_words))
    f = open('hyp_enc_dec_2L.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(str(' '.join(out_words))+ '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: The error is when using 'ax1.plot(losses, label='loss')'?

can you give the full error exactly as thrown ? ('It keeps give me errors to determine initial data.')

what exactly you want to plot? the model statistics (acc and loss while training)? or the model layers(suumary)?

Comment: Thank you for interest, I need to plot the model's layers summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using keras summary() function you can plot each of the models layers summary.

```
print('Encoder')
encoder.summary()
print('\nDecoder')
decoder.summary()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Niv Dudovitch, it was very helpful. Kindly, is there is a way to use summary() to draw the whole model to reflect the layers architecture? Something like this

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Plot-of-Neural-Network-Model-Graph.png

Comment: Try using tf.keras.utils.plot_model- Link:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model Maybe it won't work as you with because you don't define the input layer at the start. You can find information about this case here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229030/7836972

Comment: Thank you very much Niv Dudovitch, it was very helpful. I appreciate your help.